# LocatorPane, Dynamic and deleting locators

Tags: graphics, dynamic

Compare the following two code snippets :

Version 1

```
  pts = {{1, 1}, {0.2, 0.3}, {0.5, .3}}
  locpts = pts;
  Panel[
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[locpts,
     {(locpts = #; pts = #
        ) &}],
    Dynamic@
     Graphics[{Point[locpts], Dynamic[Polygon[locpts]]}, 
       PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
    LocatorAutoCreate -> All]]
```

Version 2

```
  pts = {{1, 1}, {0.2, 0.3}, {0.5, .3}}
  locpts = pts;
  Panel[
   LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[locpts,
     {(locpts = #; pts = #
        ) &}],
        Dynamic@
     Graphics[{Point[locpts], Dynamic[Polygon[pts]]}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}],
    LocatorAutoCreate -> All]]
```

Both versions are the same except for the third line from below where `Polygon[locpts]` was changed to `Polygon[pts]`.

In the first version a delete of a locator is immediately propagated in the graphic while this is not the case in the second version. I would expect no difference since I set both `pts` and `locpts` to `#`.

**Question: what is the explanation of this behavior?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the second argument of `Dynamic` in `LocatorPane[Dynamic[locpts, ...], ...]` isn't called when a locator is removed. Consider for example

```
pts = {{1, 1}, {0.2, 0.3}, {0.5, .3}}
locpts = pts;
Panel[
 LocatorPane[Dynamic[locpts, (Print[#]; locpts = #; pts = #) &], 
  Dynamic@Graphics[{Point[locpts], Polygon[pts]}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, ImageSize -> 350],
  LocatorAutoCreate -> All]]
```

then the `Print` statement will only output a line when a locator is added or moved.

Comment: This snippet does not run, but I get your point.

Comment: broken code: brackets do not match

Comment: Yes, this is an accurate reflection of the question.  Is this expected behavior? How can a removal of points best be trapped?

Comment: @ndroock1 I've fixed the code now.

Comment: Please see my previous comment ( if you haven't done so already. )

Comment: @ndroock1 I have no idea whether this is known behaviour or not. To trap the removal of points, you could compare the lengths of `locpts` and `pts` just before `Graphics...`. If `Length[locpts]<Length[pts]`, then a points was removed, and you should take appropriate action.

Comment: Sorry, for the late accept.