# LocatorPane and PlotRange

Tags: graphics, programming, dynamic

Consider the following snippet from the documentation on LocatorPane

```
  DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 0}}, 
   LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], Framed@Graphics[{}, PlotRange -> 10]]]
```

I would like to use a different shape for the LocatorPane, i.e. parallelogram, hexagon, rectangle ). ( In further processing they are 'translated' to a nice tiling. )

**Question: How can I limit the LocatorPane to a shape other than a square?**

**EDIT:**

From **kguler**'s Answer 'Locator in a Diamond' I made this so that it works with multiple locators.

```
   pts = RandomReal[1, {3, 2}];
   g = Graphics[{Blue, Polygon[Dynamic[pts]], Opacity[.1], Disk[]}, 
    PlotRange -> 1.25];
    LocatorPane[
    Dynamic[pts, (If[Apply[And, Map[Norm[#] < 1 &, pts]], pts = #, 
        pts = pts1]) &], g]
```

The limiting region is a circle here, but can be changed to any function that returns a Boolean.

There is one remaining problem and I think that it is related to the problem I found here: 
[LocatorPane, Dynamic and deleting locators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5953/locatorpane-dynamic-and-deleting-locators)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This approach uses the second argument of `Dynamic` similar to kguler's answer. In this solution you can add and remove locators using <kbd>Alt</kbd>-click (or <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-click if you're using a mac). The points are in this case restricted to hexagons, but this can easily be adapted to other shapes by changing `hexagon`. The list `centers0` is the list of centers of the tiles in the tessellation.

If the point at coordinates `pt` lie outside the tile with center `center`, `getcrd` will return new coordinates at the intersection point of the border of the tile and the line through `center` and `pt`. Note that this function isn't restricted to hexagons, so it should work for more general polygons as well (including non-convex ones).

```
DynamicModule[{hexagon, centers0, clst, getcrd, locators, translate, pts0}, 
 hexagon = N@Transpose[Through[{Re, Im}[Exp[2 Pi I Range[6]/6]]]];
 clst = centers0 = {{-3/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, {3/2, -Sqrt[3]/2}, 
   {0, -Sqrt[3]}, {0, 0}, {0, Sqrt[3]}, {-3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2}} // N;
 pts0 = locators = clst;

 getcrd[center_, pt_] := 
  Module[{edges, lambdas}, 
   edges = Partition[center + # & /@ hexagon, 2, 1, {1, 1}];
   lambdas = If[Cross[center - pt].(#1 - #2) =!= 0., 
      {Cross[center - pt].(pt - #2)/Cross[center - pt].(#1 - #2), 
        Cross[#1 - #2].(#2 - pt)/Cross[#1 - #2].(center - pt)}, 
      {Infinity, Infinity}] & @@@ edges;
   lambdas = Cases[lambdas, {a_, b_} /; 0 <= a <= 1 && 0 <= b <= 1 :> b];
   If[Length[lambdas] > 0, pt + Max[lambdas] (center - pt), pt]];

 Panel@LocatorPane[
   Dynamic[locators, (If[Length[#] > Length[clst], 
       AppendTo[clst, Nearest[centers0, #[[-1]]][[1]]]];
      locators = MapThread[getcrd, {clst, #}];
      pts0 = locators) &],
   Dynamic[If[Length[clst] > Length[locators],
     clst = clst[[Evaluate[Nearest[pts0 -> Automatic]][#][[1]] & /@ locators]];
     pts0 = locators];
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[{Dashed, Red}], FaceForm[], 
      Translate[Polygon[hexagon], centers0]}, 
     PlotRange -> {{-3, 3}, {-3, 3}}, Background -> White]], 
   LocatorAutoCreate -> True, 
   Appearance -> Graphics[{Blue, Disk[]}, ImageSize -> 10]]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 13):

Here are several variations using the second argument of `Dynamic` as in Istvan's first approach:

Locator on a diamond:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}}, 
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = Normalize[#, Norm[#, 1] &]) &], 
Graphics[{Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}}], 
Green, PointSize[.05], Dynamic[Point[pt]]}, 
PlotLabel -> Style["Locator on a Diamond", "Section", 14]], 
Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

Locator inside a diamond:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}}, 
LocatorPane[ Dynamic[pt, (pt =  If[Norm[#, 1] < 1, #, Normalize[#, Norm[#, 1] &]]) &], 
Graphics[{Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}}], 
Green, PointSize[.05], Dynamic[Point[pt]]}, 
PlotLabel -> Style["Locator inside a Diamond", "Section", 14]], 
Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

Locator inside a 3-Norm disk

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}}, 
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Norm[#, 3] < 1, #, Normalize[#, Norm[#, 1] &]]) &], 
RegionPlot[Norm[{x, y}, 3] <= 1, {x, -1.5, 1.5}, {y, -1.5, 1.5}, 
FrameTicks -> None, Epilog -> {PointSize[.05], Point[Dynamic[pt]]},
PlotLabel -> Style["Locator inside a 3-Norm Disk", "Section", 14]], 
Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

Locator below a curve:

```
DynamicModule[{pt = {0, 1}}, 
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt], 
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, Filling -> Bottom, Frame -> True, 
Epilog -> {Green, PointSize[.05], 
Point[Dynamic[{First[pt], Min[Last@pt, Sin[First[pt]]]}]]}, 
PlotLabel -> Style["Locator Below Curve", "Section", 14]], 
Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

**EDIT: Multiple locators with `LocatorAutoCreate`:**

```
DynamicModule[{pts = {{0, 1}, {0, 0}, {1, 0}}}, 
LocatorPane[
Dynamic[pts, (pts = #; pts = Function[{pnt}, 
       If[Norm[pnt, 1] < 1, pnt, Normalize[pnt, (Norm[#, 1] &)]]] /@ pts )&], 
Graphics[{Red, Line[{{-1, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 0}, {0, -1}, {-1, 0}}], 
Green, PointSize[.05], Dynamic[Point[pts]]}, 
PlotLabel -> Style["Locators inside a Diamond", "Section", 14]], 
LocatorAutoCreate -> True, Appearance -> None]]
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried to add LocatorAutoCreate to the Locator inside Diamond solution but that doesn't work. - The inside Diamond solution would be ideal because it would fit in nicely with existing code but I add all all sorts of shapes onto the diamond using locators.

Comment: @ndroock1, for multiple locators the second argument of `Dynamic` needs to be modified. I will post an edit when I get a version that works with `LocatorAutoCreate`.

Comment: Is there a solution that works with more locators? I.e. ke ep the LocatorPane features intact just restrict the region?

Comment: I think the change needed is to `Map` the normalization function inside the second argument of `Dynamic` to each element of `#`; but i need to verify that it will work.

Comment: please see my edit in the original question. I implemented what you proposed but it's not perfect yet.

Answer (score 11):

I see two ways to achieve this:

### 1. Restrict movement via Dynamic

You can restrict the movement of the `Locator` object by specifying a suitable function as a second argument for the `Dynamic` expression.

```
pt = {0, 0};
LocatorPane[Dynamic[pt, (pt = If[Total[#^2] > 1, Normalize@#, #]) &], 
     Graphics[{Dashed, Circle[]}, ImageSize -> 200]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This is easy to do with circular objects (and rectangular ones of course), but it get's complicated when the region is something more complex. Luckily, for complicated polygons, we already have a good community-solution, that simply tests whether a point is inside a polygon or not: see [here (SE)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/532/89), [here (SE)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3730/89) and [here (MathGroup)](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/e_DHwhuNkWo). Now the problem is that whenever the mouse moves out of the boundary, the coordinate pair should be modified to be the closes point **inside** the polygon. I used the distance function defined in [this demonstration](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/DistanceOfAPointToAPolygon/).

```
(* define boundary polygon *)    
poly = N@Rescale[ExampleData[{"Statistics", "WesternUgandaBorder"}]];

(* function tests whether a point is inside a polygon *)
inPolyQ = 
  Compile[{{polygon, _Real, 2}, {x, _Real}, {y, _Real}}, 
   Block[{polySides = Length[polygon], X = polygon[[All, 1]], 
     Y = polygon[[All, 2]], Xi, Yi, Yip1, wn = 0, i = 1}, 
    While[i < polySides, Yi = Y[[i]]; Yip1 = Y[[i + 1]];
     If[Yi <= y, If[Yip1 > y, Xi = X[[i]];
        If[(X[[i + 1]] - Xi) (y - Yi) - (x - Xi) (Yip1 - Yi) > 0, 
         wn++;];];, If[Yip1 <= y, Xi = X[[i]];
        If[(X[[i + 1]] - Xi) (y - Yi) - (x - Xi) (Yip1 - Yi) < 0, 
         wn--;];];]; i++]; ! wn == 0]];

(* distance between two points *)
distance[{a_, b_}, p_] := Module[{pz, az, bz, z, d1, d2},
   If[a == b, {a, Norm[p - a]},
    {pz, az, bz} = Map[First[#] + I Last[#] &, {p, a, b}];
    z = (pz - az)/(bz - az);
    If[Not[0 <= Re[z] <= 1], d1 = Norm[p - a]; d2 = Norm[p - b]; 
     If[d1 < d2, {a, d1}, {b, d2}],
     {a + Re[z] (b - a), Norm[Im[z] (b - a)]}]]];

(* closest point of a polygon to a point *)
closest[pt_, poly_] := Module[{f},
   f = Map[distance[#, pt] &, Partition[poly, 2, 1, 1]];
   First@First[Sort[f, Last@#1 <= Last@#2 &]]
   ];

pt = {0.4, 0.5};
LocatorPane[
 Dynamic[pt, (pt = 
     If[inPolyQ[poly, First@#, Last@#], #, closest[#, poly]]) &], 
 Graphics[{FaceForm@None, EdgeForm@Dashed, Polygon@poly}, 
  ImageSize -> 200]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now the locator nicely follows the boundary if the mouse is outside the area. If there are multiple adjoining areas (tiled space) each with a locator that is constrained to move inside the given polygon then there should be no problem on which locator to select when interacting with the graphics.

### 2. Restrict movement via graphics primitive

This basically involves creating your own `LocatorPane` object. The following code gives some ideas on how to do this. Let's define three hexagons, and put a dynamically updated locator in the middle of each. One can restrict the dynamically tracked mouse position to the given hexagon by reverting the point coordinate to the last valid value before leaving the hexagon (second argument of `MousePosition`). It is not perfect (a little rough around the edges) but I think it can be finetuned.

```
hexagon = {{1/2, Sqrt[3]/2}, {-(1/2), Sqrt[3]/2}, {-1, 
    0}, {-(1/2), -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {1, 0}};
{pt1, pt2, 
  pt3} = {{1.5, Sqrt[3]/2}, {1.5, -(Sqrt[3]/2)}, {0, 
   0}}; (* initial positions *)
Dynamic@{pt1, pt2, pt3}
Graphics[{
  EdgeForm@Black, GrayLevel@.9,
  EventHandler[Polygon[# + {3/2, Sqrt[3]/2} & /@ hexagon],
   {
    "MouseClicked" :> (pt1 = MousePosition["Graphics", pt1]),
    "MouseDragged" :> (pt1 = MousePosition["Graphics", pt1])
    }],
  EventHandler[Polygon[# + {3/2, -(Sqrt[3]/2)} & /@ hexagon],
   {
    "MouseClicked" :> (pt2 = MousePosition["Graphics", pt2]),
    "MouseDragged" :> (pt2 = MousePosition["Graphics", pt2])
    }],
  EventHandler[Polygon[hexagon],
   {
    "MouseClicked" :> (pt3 = MousePosition["Graphics", pt3]),
    "MouseDragged" :> (pt3 = MousePosition["Graphics", pt3])
    }],
  {Blue, Circle[Dynamic@pt1, .05], AbsolutePointSize@5, 
   Point@Dynamic@pt1},
  {Red, Circle[Dynamic@pt2, .05], AbsolutePointSize@5, 
   Point@Dynamic@pt2},
  {Darker@Green, Circle[Dynamic@pt3, .05], AbsolutePointSize@5, 
   Point@Dynamic@pt3}
  }, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> {{-1.1, 2.6}, {-2, 2}}, 
 ImageSize -> 400, ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: In an earlier stage I had to drop and replace Manipulate, I am afraid that LocatorPane has to go too. My hopes are on @kguler for the moment.

Comment: @ndroock1 Please see my edit with the nonregular polygon update.