# Coloring a honeycomb structure

Tags: graphics

I am trying to generate a honeycomb structure. With the help of [this MMA.SE question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6034/12609) & [this website](https://www.andrew.cmu.edu/user/mwdaniel/), I got

```
hexgon = Polygon[
  N@Transpose[Through[{Re, Im}[Exp[2 Pi I Range[6]/6]]]]];


points[x_, y_] := 
  Flatten[Table[{{3 m, Sqrt[3] n}, {3 m + 3/2, 
      Sqrt[3] n + Sqrt[3]/2}}, {m, 0, x}, {n, 0, y}], 2];

Graphics[Translate[
  Rotate[{RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], 
    hexgon}, \[Pi]/6], ({#[[2]], #[[1]]} &) /@ points[1, 4]]]
```

[image: Honeycomb]

How do I fill every hexagon with different color?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Translate` can translate a single graphics primitive by certain offsets, but it's not really "moving" anything. Rather it creates a copy and puts it on the specified location. If you give it several locations it will create several copies. `RGBColor[RandomReal[],RandomReal[],RandomReal[]]` will only be called once because each is a copy of the other. But if you execute `Translate` once for each location, you get a new "object" every time. So all I had to do was move the `/@ points[1,4]` outside of `Translate`.

```
hexgon = Polygon[
   N@Transpose[Through[{Re, Im}[Exp[2 Pi I Range[6]/6]]]]];

points[x_, y_] := 
  Flatten[Table[{{3 m, Sqrt[3] n}, {3 m + 3/2, 
      Sqrt[3] n + Sqrt[3]/2}}, {m, 0, x}, {n, 0, y}], 2];

Graphics[
 Translate[
    Rotate[{RGBColor[RandomReal[], RandomReal[], RandomReal[]], 
      hexgon}, \[Pi]/6],
    ({#[[2]], #[[1]]})
    ] & /@ points[1, 4]
 ]
```

[image: colored hexagons]